# How can I use a switch in a tableview cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, protocols

In iOS Swift 4.0 I have a switch in a tableview cell. However, whenever I tap it, it crashes with a `unrecognized selector sent to instance` message. I haven't been able to figure out a solution.

Here's how I have been trying to do it...

TableView Cell:

```
import UIKit

protocol PromoCellSubclassDelegate : class {
    func switchValueChanged(sender: UISwitch, cell: PromoCellSubclass)
}

class PromoCellSubclass: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var pageName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var activeSwitch: UISwitch!

    var delegate: PromoCellSubclassDelegate?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        self.delegate = nil
    }

    @IBAction func ValueChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        self.delegate?.switchValueChanged(sender: sender, cell: self)
    }
}
```

Parent ViewController:

```
class ProviderPromoViewController: Y2goViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, PromoCellSubclassDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

...

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! PromoCellSubclass

    cell.delegate = self
    cell.pageName.text = promos[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].promoName
    cell.setBackground()

    let promoStatus = promos[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].statusCd!

    switch promoStatus {
    case 1:
        cell.activeSwitch.isOn = false
    case 2:
        cell.activeSwitch.isOn = true
    default:
        cell.activeSwitch.isOn = false
    }

    return cell
}

...


func switchValueChanged(sender: UISwitch, cell: PromoCellSubclass) {
    guard let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else {
        return
    }

    print("Switch changed on row \((indexPath as NSIndexPath).row)")
}
```

SwitchValueChanged is getting called and works properly, but it crashes as soon as it finishes. What did I miss?

Edit:
The complete error message is:

> 2018-04-19 20:55:20.708538-0600 Y2GOsp[74562:15808974]
>   -[Y2GOsp.PromoCellSubclass switchValueChanged:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd356838000 2018-04-19 20:55:53.253801-0600
>   Y2GOsp[74562:15808974] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Y2GOsp.PromoCellSubclass
>   switchValueChanged:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x7fd356838000'

Comment: What's the crash message?

Comment: Seems correct, should make the delegate a `weak var`, but no other problem i see with your code, does it print the line or return, post the whole error message here

Comment: I just posted an edit with the complete message.

Comment: although this delegation method is completely right, but if it is giving you an error, why don't to make action of switch directly to ParentViewController? By doing that way, you can find indexpath of cell using position of switch in tableview.

Comment: Tell me tableview is Grouped or not?

Comment: It is not grouped

Comment: @Lastmboy Can you add `cellForRowAt` method?

Comment: @SharadPaghadal I changed it to `weak var`, but it didn't solve the error.

Comment: @trungdu I do have `cellForRowAt` implemented. I edited my original post to include it. However, that doesn't help me track when a switch is changed.

Comment: @Lastmboy Seem like everything is correct. Try to clear your IBOutlet connections and connect them again

Comment: @SharadPaghadal I tried putting the action right in the view controller, but then I get the error indicating that it can't be used where there are repeating values.

Comment: @trungduc Your solution worked! I cleared all IBOutlets and reconnected and it is now working ok. Post your answer if you like. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear your IBOutlet connections, connect them again and it will work ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why you used this class word in protocol declaration, there is no need of

```
protocol PromoCellSubclassDelegate : class {
    func switchValueChanged(sender: UISwitch, cell: PromoCellSubclass)
}
```

And what is this prepareForReuse, this is also not required..

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    self.delegate = nil
}
```

Otherwise all code is right... Use Exceptional Breakpoint, debugger will stop where it crashing..

Comment: How would you do it without the protocol? Declare the IBAction right in the controller?

Comment: No I am talikng about Class word in protocol declaration, there is no need of that word

Comment: Oh. Ok. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all the outlet connections are done properly, if not remove the connections and once again create the outlets.

I hope this could be of some help.